# Any way to exclude BlazorDebugProxy directory from Release Blazor WASM apps?

Tags: blazor-webassembly

When publishing "Release" builds, the output contains a BlazorDebugProxy folder. That folder is about 18mb. My understanding is this directory contains everything needed to get Chrome to debug Blazor Web Assemblies and I do not want this in my Release/Production builds. I'd like to keep my release builds / deploy tidy. Can I somehow exclude this directory from my publish?

Bonus information: This directory doesn't even respect my csproj specifications, like SatelliteResourceLanguages, for example, even tho is set to en;fr, the BlazorDebugProxy contains a bunch of satellite assemblies for russian, polish, etc...

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: It's a know issue and no workaround exists yet https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25102

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to do this in net5.0 by adding this to my Blazor WASM host .csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <BlazorWebAssemblyOmitDebugProxyOutput>true</BlazorWebAssemblyOmitDebugProxyOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Found this property in the build .targets inside the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server package

Comment: Ignore my previous comment this actually works. Thanks @ian

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Pethical, there is an issue on [aspnetcore's github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25102).
No workaround for now.